# How to sovle self-defining function to count can't work

Tags: r, function

I write a function to count daily number of people in hospital but it can't work when the number is 0 in some days.
my function:

```
tsdata2 <- function(df){

  t.f <- as.data.frame(table(df$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(whole =Freq)
  ## sex
  man.d <- df %>% filter(GENDER == 1) 
  man.f <- as.data.frame(table(man.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(man =Freq)

  woman.d <- df %>% filter(GENDER == 2) 
  woman.f <- as.data.frame(table(woman.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(woman =Freq)

  ## age 65
  agelo65.d <- df %>% filter(age_group65 == 1)
  agelo65.f <- as.data.frame(table(agelo65.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(agelo65 =Freq)

  ageup65.d <- df %>% filter(age_group65 == 2)
  ageup65.f <- as.data.frame(table(ageup65.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(ageupwith65 =Freq)

  ## age 10
  age10.1.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 1)
  age10.1.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.1.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(agelo40 =Freq)

  age10.2.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 2)
  age10.2.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.2.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(age41_50 =Freq)

  age10.3.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 3)
  age10.3.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.3.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(age51_60 =Freq)

  age10.4.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 4)
  age10.4.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.4.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(age61_70 =Freq)

  age10.5.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 5)
  age10.5.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.5.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(age71_80 =Freq)

  age10.6.d <- df %>% filter(age_group10 == 6)
  age10.6.d.f <- as.data.frame(table(age10.6.d$DATE_INHOSPITAL2)) %>% rename(ageup80 =Freq)

  datebreaks<-seq(as.Date("2014-01-01"),as.Date("2018-12-31"),by="1 day")

  full <- data.frame(Var1 = as.character(datebreaks) )


  result <- full %>% 
    left_join(t.f) %>% 
    left_join(man.f) %>% 
    left_join(woman.f) %>% 
    left_join(agelo65.f) %>% 
    left_join(ageup65.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.1.d.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.2.d.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.3.d.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.4.d.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.5.d.f) %>% 
    left_join(age10.6.d.f) %>% replace(., is.na(.), 0)

  return(result)
}



list <- split(total,total$DISEASE_CODE1_2to3)

test <- map(list,tsdata2)
```

I think the error was because the number of hospital admissions on a given day was zero.

How can I improve this code that it can work even the number is zero.

```
test <- map(list,tsdata2)
Joining, by = "Var1"
Joining, by = "Var1"
Joining, by = "Var1"
Joining, by = "Var1"
Joining, by = "Var1"
Joining, by = "Var1"
Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common variables
```

Comment: That is some dreadful code with many repetitive operations that should be approached programmatically. It would be very helpful if you were to provide minimal sample data and your expected output. This seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, and there is most probably a better way to achieve what you're after. But in order for us to give specific help we need specific (minimal) sample data.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such an error thrown is that you are applying `left_join` on empty data frames with no columns to join. Along your data frame filtering and contingency table creation, data frames with no columns to join were generated. Please see below the simulation :

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])
df2 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, c = letters[11:20])
df2 <- df2[,-c(1, 2)]
str(df2)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  0 variables

df2 %>% left_join(df1)
```

The code above throws an error:

> Error: `by` required, because the data sources have no common
>   variables Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace

To avoid such a problem you can implement simple check if the data frame is with no columns then change to dummy data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = letters[1:10])
df2 <- df1[,-c(1, 2)]
df_dummy <- data.frame(a = 1, c = 0)
if(ncol(df2) == 0) df2 <- df_dummy
df1 %>% left_join(df2)
# 
# Joining, by = "a"
# a b  c
# 1   1 a  0
# 2   2 b NA
# 3   3 c NA
# 4   4 d NA
# 5   5 e NA
# 6   6 f NA
# 7   7 g NA
# 8   8 h NA
# 9   9 i NA
# 10 10 j NA
```